# How can i display orders based on criteria in odoo 10?

Tags: python, odoo, erp

I have scenario in point of sale module. Manager can view (manages) all orders list against each sales person. Where as each sales person manages and view all his/ her own orders.
How can create expression where individual sales person can view their orders by the given below express. i want expression work for both.

```
<record id="rule_pos_multi_company" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">Point Of Sale Order</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_pos_order" />
    <field name="global" eval="True" />
    <field name="domain_force">[('user_id', '=', user.id)]</field>
```

Comment: Default  given in POS

<field name="domain_force">[('company_id', '=', user.company_id.id)]</field>

Answer (score 0):

To make manager view all orders of employees he is responsible of, you have to use one more condition --> ('user_id.parent_id', '=', user.id)

use ***or*** condition

code:-

```
<field name="domain_force">['|'('user_id', '=', user.id),('user_id.parent_id', '=', user.id)]</field>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tired but generating error ..

here is actual given in security file against Orders list

<field name="domain_force">[('company_id', '=', user.company_id.id)]</field>